# Layers Created from table not saving?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, linear-referencing

I'm new to QGIS.

I have imported a shapefile for a road network. I have then imported a table containing condition data about the network. I have used the LRS plugin and the data displays perfectly and the "Attribute table" is full of data.  I have saved the project, but then when I close QGIS, then reopen it and open the project, whilst the condition layers are listed in the layers panel, none of its data is displayed and its "attribute table" is empty.

How do I save the project so that when I open it, I can continue where I left of rather than having to recreate everything?

Comment: Some plugins like LRS plugin stores the output into the memory. You might need to either save it to an external file or use [Memory Layer Saver](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MemoryLayerSaver/) plugin to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was as a result of the LRS creating scratch layers. Save the scratch layer as permanent and it reopens correctly.